# getelementptr has -1 as the first index operand

Tags: compilation, llvm, llvm-ir

I'm reading the IR of nginx generated by Clang. In function `ngx_event_expire_timers`, there are some `getelementptr` instructions with `i64 -1` as first index operand. For example,

```
%handler = getelementptr inbounds %struct.ngx_rbtree_node_s, %struct.ngx_rbtree_node_s* %node.addr.0.i, i64 -1, i32 2
```

I know the first index operand will be used as an offset to the first operand. But what does a negative offset mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GEP instruction is perfectly fine with negative indices. 
In this case you have something like:

```
node arr[100]; 
node* ptr = arr[50]; 
if ( (ptr-1)->value == ptr->value) 
  // then ...
```

GEP with negative indices just calculate the offset to the base pointer into the other direction. There is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: That's true. But the purpose of using this negative value is interesting. I have explained it in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Considering what is doing inside nginx source code, the semantics of the getelementptr instruction is interesting. It's the result of two lines of C source code:

```
ev = (ngx_event_t *) ((char *) node - offsetof(ngx_event_t, timer));
ev->handler(ev);
```

`node` is of type `ngx_rbtree_node_t`, which is a member of `ev`'s type `ngx_event_t`. That is like:

```
struct ngx_event_t {
   ....
   struct ngx_rbtree_node_t time;
   ....
};

struct ngx_event_t *ev;
struct ngx_rbtree_node_t *node;
```

`timer` is the name of struct `ngx_event_t` member where `node` should point to.

```
                 |<- ngx_rbtree_node_t ->|
|<-               ngx_event_t                      ->|
------------------------------------------------------
| (some data)    | "time"                | (some data)
------------------------------------------------------
^                ^
ev               node
```

The graph above shows the layout of an instance of `ngx_event_t`. The result of `offsetof(ngx_event_t, time)` is 40. That means the `some data` before `time` is of 40 bytes. And the size of `ngx_rbtree_node_t` is also 40 bytes， by coincidence. So the `i64 -1` in the first index oprand of getelementptr instruction computes the base address of the `ngx_event_t` containing `node`, which is 40 bytes ahead of `node`.

`handler` is another member of `ngx_event_t`, which is 16 bytes behind the base of `ngx_event_t`. By (another) coincidence, the third member of `ngx_rbtree_node_t` is also 16 bytes behind the base address of `ngx_rbtree_node_t`. So the `i32 2` in getelementptr instruction will add 16 bytes to `ev`, to get the address of `handler`.

Note that the 16 bytes is computed from the layout of `ngx_rbtree_node_t`, but not `ngx_event_t`. Clang must have done some computations to ensure the correctness of the getelementptr instruction. Before use the value of `%handler`, there is a bitcast instruction which casts `%handler` to a function pointer type.

What Clang has done breaks the type transformation process defined in C source code. But the result is the exactly same.